# Unable to find control id 'ID of your Meter' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'IDofyourMeterRequird'

Tags: asp.net

I have this error when I run the `register.aspx` in Visual Studio after I added some fields.  The fields are `id`, `meter`, and `address`.

This is the code:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ID of your Meter">ID of your Meter:</asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ID of your Meter" ErrorMessage="ID is required." ToolTip="ID is required." ValidationGroup="RegisterUser">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Error comes because you have

```
AssociatedControlID="ID of your Meter"
ControlToValidate="ID of your Meter"
```

and you should have there server IDs of controls which you are going to associate with

for instance like that in your case (you should anyway consider to change naming to be more descriptive):

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="TextBox1">ID of your Meter:</asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="ID is required." ToolTip="ID is required." ValidationGroup="RegisterUser">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: mmm so what i need to do to solve this problem create new table of this fields ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied/pasted something from a tutorial and never changed it to work in your code:

```
AssociatedControlID="ID of your Meter"
ControlToValidate="ID of your Meter"
```

What/where is your "Meter"?  You need to put in these attributes the server-side `ID` property of a control.

Notice how the server-side controls that you are using have `ID` properties:

```
ID="Label1"
ID="TextBox1"
ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
```

These `ID` properties need to be unique, and that's what those other fields are looking for.  The unique `ID` of a particular control.

Side note: You probably want to use more meaningful names for your `ID`s.  It makes the code a lot easier to support and maintain.

Comment: This seems to be some rest of the standart code in a standard asp.net project not a tutorial ;-)

Comment: so from where i change  is to create data with the same ID in the server ,it to be run as steps 
and thnks in advance

Comment: @AhmedMahrous: I'm sorry, but I can't make out what you're asking in that comment.

Comment: @NikolajZander yea it that in register form in asp.net

Comment: @David i need to solve problem so what is steps what i change in my code

Comment: @AhmedMahrous: Well, don't be offended by this, but the first step would be to learn how ASP.NET works.  Your server controls (such as `TextBox`) are all identified by an `id` property.  They use this property to reference each other.  Currently your code is trying to reference a control with an `id` of `"ID of your Meter"` which, clearly, is not correct.  Whatever your "meter" is, whatever server control represents that concept, you need to put its `id` value where you currently have the string `"ID of your Meter"`.